# Disabling Bluetooth on 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, power-management, 18.04

There's no option to disable Bluetooth permanently but under energy settings you can select to disable both Bluetooth and wifi when not in use. Does this mean that Bluetooth gets disabled automatically? I never use it and want to save power.